# ECT with slim/jade like syntax

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, pug, template-engine, slim-lang

I am looking for a coffeescript client side templating engine with slim like syntax..[ECT](http://ectjs.com/) currently supports coffeescript template but with html syntax

Answer (score 1):

try [coffeeKup](http://coffeekup.org/) . As I know it looks like jade